# Why can't I load a bitmap from an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask, android-bitmap

I am trying to load bitmaps using an AsyncTask, in order to load them outside UI Thread as it was too slow.
Unfortunatly, I am having issues when starting the app.

The AsyncTask is a class declared inside a "BitmapBank" class, used to handle the different bitmaps of the app. I did it that way to avoid the fact that you can't return something from an Asynctask.

Here is my code :

```
    public Bitmap loadBitmap(Drawable drawable){
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap scaleImage(Bitmap bitmap, int ratio){
        float widthHeightRatio = (float)(bitmap.getHeight())/(float)(bitmap.getWidth());
        int scaleHeight = (int)(widthHeightRatio * AppConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH/ratio);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, AppConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH/ratio, scaleHeight, false);
    }

    private class BitmapTask extends AsyncTask<Drawable, Void, Void> {

        public BitmapTask(){
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Drawable... drawables) {
            rocket = prepareBitmap(drawables[0]);
            astronaut = prepareBitmap(drawables[1]);
            bloc = prepareBitmap(drawables[2]);
            background = prepareBitmap(drawables[3]);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            rocket = scaleImage(rocket, 10);
            astronaut = scaleImage(astronaut, 20);
            bloc = scaleImage(bloc, AppConstants.NB_BLOCS);
            background = scaleImage(background, 1);
        }
    }
```

And here is the logcat :

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 121701132 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 86MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:975)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:946)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:913)
        at com.example.myapplication.BitmapBank.prepareBitmap(BitmapBank.java:93)
        at com.example.myapplication.BitmapBank$BitmapTask.doInBackground(BitmapBank.java:117)
        at com.example.myapplication.BitmapBank$BitmapTask.doInBackground(BitmapBank.java:106)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks if you can have a look !

Comment: The error message is clear: you need ~121 MB for the image but there are only ~16 MB available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where does it come from ? It appears only when using the asynctask...

Comment: @BigT it not only appear if you use asynctask.it's all about that your heap memory is not enough to allocate a new bitmap into it -> throw a outofmemory exception.search "outofmemory" and "heap" for more detail :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, actually I am passing appcontext through several classes, do you think the memory leak can come from there ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the "Glide" library that automatically handles your problem. Glide is an open source Android library for loading animated images, videos and GIFs. With Glide you can upload and display media from many different sources, such as remote servers or the local file system.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(new File(fileUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
    .into(profileAvatar);
```

Comment: Many thanks ! Does it work if my images are vectors ?